# Login to ecr and push build image to it with the help of gorelaeser

Tags: goreleaser

I have created make release process with the help of  gorelaeser .
But in my case I need to build and push image to ECR.
Currently before building image I'm login to ecr and then building image but don't know how to push image via gorelaeser.

## .goreleaser.yml

dockers:

```
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
image_templates:
- "myuser/myimage:latest"
- "myuser/myimage:{{ .Tag }}"
- "myuser/myimage:{{ .Tag }}-{{ .Env.GO_VERSION }}"
- "myuser/myimage:v{{ .Major }}"
- "gcr.io/myuser/myimage:latest"
skip_push: false
dockerfile: Dockerfile
use: docker
build_flag_templates:
- "--build-arg=FOO={{.Env.Bar}}"
- "--platform=linux/arm64
push_flags:
- --tls-verify=false
```

Tried changing skip_push value to true also

Answer (score 0):

GoReleaser will push the images automatically in the end of the process if you run `goreleaser release`, provided that `docker` is authorized to do so.

GoReleaser does not push if you're running `goreleaser build` or `goreleaser release --snapshot` though, so maybe you're doing one of these?